# Jodometer jQuery

Tags: jquery

I´ve downloaded a jOdometer jQuery and uploaded it to my website.
I wonder how I can get the numbers to continue changing even if I reload the page. Right now the numbers resets to it´s start value every time i reload the page.

Thanks

Edit:
I´ll do this and maybe you can help me to paste the correct code:

`code`
        $(function(){

```
            $('.counter1').jOdometer({increment: 12.58,speed: 500, numbersImage: 'http://facebookmarket.se/wp-content/plugins/jodometer/images/jodometer-numbers.png', spaceNumbers: 5, offsetRight:10,heightNumber: 85,widthNumber: 38,counterStart: '0000000.00',counterEnd: false,widthDot: 25,easing: 'linear',});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set the `counterStart` [configuration option](https://github.com/jesucarr/jOdometer/blob/master/jquery.jodometer.js) server-side:

```
$('.counter').jOdometer({
  counterStart: '1000.25'
});
```

From the documentation:

> **counterStart**: Number we start with. To get a specific number of digits/decimals it has to be a string (e.g. '0005.50') `// Default: '0000.00'`

Depending on your server-side language of choice, the actual implementation of this will vary. If you were serving these pages up with PHP, and pulling a start value from the database, you could place that in your output:

```
echo "<script>$('.counter').jOdometer({counterStart:'$start_number'});</script>";
```

Where `$start_number` is the value retrieved from our database.

Comment: it doesnt seem to work.. I´ve set a counterStart value like that but still not changing :S

Comment: script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   
   $('.counter1').jOdometer({increment: 12.58,speed: 500, numbersImage: 'LINK', spaceNumbers: 5, offsetRight:10,heightNumber: 85,widthNumber: 38,counterStart: '0023674.00',counterEnd: '5326346.00',widthDot: 25,easing: 'linear',});
  });
 </script>

Comment: @FredrikWeiland And I'm assuming that starts the counter at "0023674.00" each time you load the page?

Comment: @FredrikWeiland You'll need to replace that static value with a dynamic value as I demonstrated in my PHP example above.

Comment: Should I replace the entire script with <?php echo "<script>$('.counter').jOdometer({counterStart:'$start_number'});</script>";?> ?

Comment: Stupd enter sends the message

this is what I have
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   
    $('.counter1').jOdometer({increment: 12.58,speed: 500, numbersImage: 'LINK', spaceNumbers: 5, offsetRight:10,heightNumber: 85,widthNumber: 38,counterStart: '<?php echo $row['ID'];?>',counterEnd: '5326346.00',widthDot: 25,easing: 'linear',});
  });
 </script>

and the "$row['ID']" have I fetched from the database but the problem is still there

Comment: @FredrikWeiland Can you please provide your full PHP in an edit to your question above?